# Facing error like-*Access denied You don't have permission to iam:GetAccountSummary

Tags: devops

I was working on AWS adding user in IAM console  but here it is showing access denied error.
how to mitigate this error.

I took help for google and YouTube but I didn't got fruitful result.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are logged in to that account using a Role and that Role doesn't have all the required permissions to view the IAM Console.